# Pandas read_SQL response is supposed to be in Hebrew, but I get gibberish instead

Tags: python, sql, pandas, encoding, teradata

I have a python script in which I make an SQL query to my Teradata server.

I use teradatasql python library for that:

```
conn = tdSQL.connect(logmech=logmech, host=host)
query = "SELECT * FROM table"
df = pandas.read_sql(query, conn)
```

And instead of getting the "Hebrew" column, I get the "Gibberish" column:

```
    Hebrew  Gibberish   hebrew_char2hexint
0   אילת    àéìú    E0E9ECFA
1   אשדוד   àùãåã   E0F9E3E5E3
2   אשקלון  àùœìåï  E0F9F7ECE5EF
3   באר שבע áàø ùáò E1E0F820F9E1F2
4   בית שמש áéú ùîù E1E9FA20F9EEF9
5   בני ברק áÐé áøœ E1F0E920E1F8F7
6   דימונה  ãéîåÐä  E3E9EEE5F0E4
7   המשולש דרום äîùåìù ãøåí E4EEF9E5ECF920E3F8E5ED
8   המשולש צפון äîùåìù öôåï E4EEF9E5ECF920F6F4E5EF
9   הרצליה  äøöìéä  E4F8F6ECE9E4
10  חדרה    çãøä    E7E3F8E4
11  חולון   çåìåï   E7E5ECE5EF
12  חיפה    çéôä    E7E9F4E4
13  חצור הגלילית    çöåø äâìéìéú    E7F6E5F820E4E2ECE9ECE9FA
14  טבריה   èáøéä   E8E1F8E9E4
15  יהוד    éäåã    E9E4E5E3
16  ירושלים éøåùìéí E9F8E5F9ECE9ED
17  כפר סבא ëôø ñáà EBF4F820F1E1E0
18  לא קיים ìà œééí ECE020F7E9E9ED
19  מגדל העמק   îâãì äòîœ   EEE2E3EC20E4F2EEF7
20  מודיעין îåãéòéï EEE5E3E9F2E9EF
21  מעלה אדומים îòìä àãåîéí EEF2ECE420E0E3E5EEE9ED
22  נהריה   Ðäøéä   F0E4F8E9E4
23  נתיבות  Ðúéáåú  F0FAE9E1E5FA
24  נתניה   ÐúÐéä   F0FAF0E9E4
25  עפולה   òôåìä   F2F4E5ECE4
26  פתח תקוה    ôúç úœåä    F4FAE720FAF7E5E4
27  קריות   œøéåú   F7F8E9E5FA
28  קרית גת œøéú âú F7F8E9FA20E2FA
29  קרית טבעון  œøéú èáòåï  F7F8E9FA20E8E1F2E5EF
30  קרית שמונה  œøéú ùîåÐä  F7F8E9FA20F9EEE5F0E4
31  ראשון לציון øàùåï ìöéåï F8E0F9E5EF20ECF6E9E5EF
32  רחובות  øçåáåú  F8E7E5E1E5FA
33  רמת גן  øîú âï  F8EEFA20E2EF
34  תל אביב יפו úì àáéá éôå FAEC20E0E1E9E120E9F4E5
```

Any ideas why does it happen and how to solve that?

I did manage to partially solve the problem -

```
df2.Gibberish[0].encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('ISO-8859-8')
```

returns:

```
'אילת'
```

It also works with the second row. But when I try it on the third row:

```
df2.Gibberish[2].encode('ISO-8859-1').decode('ISO-8859-8')
```

I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0153' in position 2: ordinal not in range(256)
```

The only way I managed not to receive any errors is with the following encoding and decoding:

```
df.Gibberish[index].encode('ISO-8859-15').decode('cp1255')
```

But the translation is not perfect:

```
0   באר שבע
1   ב׀י בר½
2   דימו׀ה
3   אילת
4   בית שמש
5   המשולש דרום
6   המשולש צפון
7   הרצליה
8   אשדוד
9   אש½לון
10  חולון
11  חדרה
12  חיפה
13  חצור הגלילית
14  ׀הריה
15  ׀ת׀יה
16  ׀תיבות
17  יהוד
18  טבריה
19  ירושלים
20  כפר סבא
21  לא ½יים
22  מודיעין
23  מגדל העמ½
24  מעלה אדומים
25  ראשון לציון
26  רחובות
27  ½ריות
28  ½רית גת
29  ½רית טבעון
30  ½רית שמו׀ה
31  רמת גן
32  עפולה
33  פתח ת½וה
34  תל אביב יפו
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share your table as text. Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Read more about [images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404).

Comment: Which encoding does the column in question have in the database? Looks almost like it's ISO-8859-8 that is wrongly handled as if it were ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson is right. You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: for instance, `'השפה'.encode( 'iso8859_8').decode( 'iso8859_1')` returns `äùôä`… Another example: `'השפה האוניברסלית המקורית'.encode( 'cp1255').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `äùôä äàåðéáøñìéú äî÷åøéú`.

Comment: Ok, that sounds about right. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?
The column was created as: "Main_City_Name VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC"

Comment: As the name implies, LATIN doesn't store Hebrew, must be defined as `CHARACTER SET UNICODE`.

Comment: Well.. I cannot change the DB, it is a different company's DB which I access.
And I guess it can store it, as it does store it.
Does any of you have an idea of how to read the data properly?

Comment: Then ask the company how the data is retrieved the right way (Teradata supports defining your own character sets, but I've never actually seen that and I don't think it's still returned as CHARACTER SET LATIN). How do you know what's the hebrew word? Can you show the output when you `select char2hexint(hebrew column)...`?

Comment: Most, but not all, of the Teradata "server LATIN" code points are the same as corresponding Unicode / Latin-1 code points. Maybe build a mapping table to "undo" the Teradata LATIN to Unicode translation, something like `back2latin1 = astring.maketrans('\uFFFD\u0161\xFD\xA4\xDD\u0160\xF0\u0152\u0178\xFE\xD0\u0153\xFF\xDE\u20AC','\x1A\xA0\xA4\xA8\xB4\xB8\xD0\xD7\xDD\xDE\xF0\xF7\xFD\xFE\xFF')
` then apply  `.translate(back2latin1)` method  before doing the Latin-1 encoding.

Comment: Added a "char2hexint" column. I hope it is what you meant. @dnoeth

Comment: The client character set used for loading was probably Hebrew1255_5A0, which implements codepage Windows-1255, a superset of ISO-8859-8. Thus `decode('cp1255')` should work.

Comment: @dnoeth decoding with this character set is actually the best option I've had so far. But which character set should I use to encode? I used ISO-8859-15 but it didn't give me perfect results

Comment: I don't have expertise in this area. ½ seems to be xF7. Teradata's internal latin character set is an extended ASCII, a mix of 8859-1 and 8859-15. Try to approach the DBA to open an incident with Teradata support, they should know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that it is not supported to store Hebrew characters in a `CHARACTER SET LATIN` column.

The Teradata JDBC Driver offers the `CLIENT_CHARSET` connection parameter, so a Java application could query the data by omitting the `CHARSET=` connection parameter, and specifying the `CLIENT_CHARSET=cp1255` connection parameter.

Please note [the warning given](https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#URL_CLIENT_CHARSET) for the `CLIENT_CHARSET` connection parameter: *Not recommended for normal use. Use at your own risk. Data corruption will occur if the wrong Java character set is specified. Teradata cannot provide any guarantees of data fidelity or quality when this connection parameter is used.*

In contrast, the Teradata SQL Driver for Python always uses the UTF8 session character set, and does not offer the `charset=` or the `client_charset=` connection parameters.

For the Python driver, you can use a workaround by modifying your query to use the `CHAR2HEXINT` and `TO_BYTES` function to convert the `CHARACTER SET LATIN` column values into `VARBYTE` values, and then in your Python script use the Python `.decode("cp1255")` method on the `bytes` column values in the result set to convert the cp1255-encoded `bytes` values into Python string values.

Example Python script:

```py
import teradatasql
with teradatasql.connect (host="whomooz", user="guest", password="please") as con:
 with con.cursor () as cur:
  cur.execute ("create volatile table tab1 (c1 integer, c2 varchar(100) character set latin) on commit preserve rows")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 0, _LATIN 'E0E9ECFA'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 1, _LATIN 'E0F9E3E5E3'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 2, _LATIN 'E0F9F7ECE5EF'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 3, _LATIN 'E1E0F820F9E1F2'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 4, _LATIN 'E1E9FA20F9EEF9'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 5, _LATIN 'E1F0E920E1F8F7'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 6, _LATIN 'E3E9EEE5F0E4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 7, _LATIN 'E4EEF9E5ECF920E3F8E5ED'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 8, _LATIN 'E4EEF9E5ECF920F6F4E5EF'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values ( 9, _LATIN 'E4F8F6ECE9E4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (10, _LATIN 'E7E3F8E4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (11, _LATIN 'E7E5ECE5EF'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (12, _LATIN 'E7E9F4E4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (13, _LATIN 'E7F6E5F820E4E2ECE9ECE9FA'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (14, _LATIN 'E8E1F8E9E4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (15, _LATIN 'E9E4E5E3'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (16, _LATIN 'E9F8E5F9ECE9ED'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (17, _LATIN 'EBF4F820F1E1E0'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (18, _LATIN 'ECE020F7E9E9ED'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (19, _LATIN 'EEE2E3EC20E4F2EEF7'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (20, _LATIN 'EEE5E3E9F2E9EF'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (21, _LATIN 'EEF2ECE420E0E3E5EEE9ED'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (22, _LATIN 'F0E4F8E9E4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (23, _LATIN 'F0FAE9E1E5FA'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (24, _LATIN 'F0FAF0E9E4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (25, _LATIN 'F2F4E5ECE4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (26, _LATIN 'F4FAE720FAF7E5E4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (27, _LATIN 'F7F8E9E5FA'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (28, _LATIN 'F7F8E9FA20E2FA'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (29, _LATIN 'F7F8E9FA20E8E1F2E5EF'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (30, _LATIN 'F7F8E9FA20F9EEE5F0E4'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (31, _LATIN 'F8E0F9E5EF20ECF6E9E5EF'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (32, _LATIN 'F8E7E5E1E5FA'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (33, _LATIN 'F8EEFA20E2EF'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("insert into tab1 values (34, _LATIN 'FAEC20E0E1E9E120E9F4E5'XCV)")
  cur.execute ("select c1, trim(to_bytes(trim(char2hexint(c2)), translate('base16' using unicode_to_latin))) from tab1 order by 1")
  [ print (row [0], row [1].decode ("cp1255")) for row in cur.fetchall () ]
```

Produces the following output:

```
0 אילת
1 אשדוד
2 אשקלון
3 באר שבע
4 בית שמש
5 בני ברק
6 דימונה
7 המשולש דרום
8 המשולש צפון
9 הרצליה
10 חדרה
11 חולון
12 חיפה
13 חצור הגלילית
14 טבריה
15 יהוד
16 ירושלים
17 כפר סבא
18 לא קיים
19 מגדל העמק
20 מודיעין
21 מעלה אדומים
22 נהריה
23 נתיבות
24 נתניה
25 עפולה
26 פתח תקוה
27 קריות
28 קרית גת
29 קרית טבעון
30 קרית שמונה
31 ראשון לציון
32 רחובות
33 רמת גן
34 תל אביב יפו
```

Answer (score 0):

I just extracted the mapping from Teradata documentation (H5A0SUCD.txt file) and put it in a `OTranslate` :-)

This should work the same as the `Hebrew1255_5A0` client character set:

```
OTranslate
 (  -- convert to "gibberish" unicode
   Translate(hewbrew USING latin_to_unicode) 
    -- H5A0SUCD.txt: characters >= x80
  ,_latin '8082838485868788898B9192939495969798999BA0A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8A9AAABACADAEAFB0B1B2B3B4B5B6B7B8B9BABBBCBDBEBFC0C1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9CBCCCDCECFD0D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8E0E1E2E3E4E5E6E7E8E9EAEBECEDEEEFF0F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8F9FAFDFE'XCV
    -- mapped hebrew characters >= x80
  ,_Unicode '20AC201A0192201E20262020202102C62030203920182019201C201D20222013201402DC2122203A00A000A100A200A320AA00A500A600A700A800A900D700AB00AC00AD00AE00AF00B000B100B200B300B400B500B600B700B800B900F700BB00BC00BD00BE00BF05B005B105B205B305B405B505B605B705B805B905BB05BC05BD05BE05BF05C005C105C205C305F005F105F205F305F405D005D105D205D305D405D505D605D705D805D905DA05DB05DC05DD05DE05DF05E005E105E205E305E405E505E605E705E805E905EA200E200F'xcv
 )
```

Would be a perfect use case for a SQL UDF.